# C++11 std::async in Android NDK does not work

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk

I have tried to get following sample code working to know whether asynchronous programming is working in Android NDK. Though NDK has the STL `<future>` which gets recognized as a header, the `std::async` is not getting recognized are not getting recognized. The code I tried to use was the following:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo 
{
  Foo() : data(0) {}
  void sum(int i) { data +=i;}
  int data;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto f = std::async(&Foo::sum, &foo, 42);
    f.get();
    std::cout << foo.data << "\n";
}
```

Also all the include paths have been set to the specified folder under Properties->Paths and Symbols

```
Errors
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<void (Foo::*)(int), void (Foo::*)(int), Foo*, int>::type {aka struct std::future<void>}' Sample.cpp  /Project12/jni  line 50 C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
declaration of 'std::__async_sfinae_helper<void (Foo::*)(int), void (Foo::*)(int), Foo*, int>::type {aka struct std::future<void>}' Project12       line 111, external location: D:\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r8e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.6\include\future C/C++ Problem
```

Answer (score 9):

Curently Android NDK does not incorporate all of the C++11 features. Clang 3.3 compiler from NDK r9b  is C++11-feature complete, however, `STL` and `stdlib` on Android are not.

To use the most recent `C++11` feature set in Android use Clang 3.3 compiler from `Android NDK r9b`. Put this line into your `Application.mk` file:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

Also, add `-std=c++11` switch to the `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` variable:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: still I am not getting it... In fact I am not able to use even the enum defined in <future>.... Is it a problem with Eclipse or the ndk or the library I do not know

Comment: It is the problem with the NDK. Just wait for the update. Clang 3.3 and the new stdlib will be there one day.

Comment: @user2508941 NDK r9 is out, with clang 3.3.

Comment: @Samveen: And r9 still does not incorporate all the features (mostly STL and stdlib)

Comment: @SergeyK. It was more to update your answer about the availability of r9 and clang 3.3 than comment on C++11 feature set support in clang 3.3.