# Error when compiling cocos2d-x for android

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have a problem when compiling a project of cocos2d-x for android, the executing brand me these errors...

```
Compile++ thumb  : game_shared <= Terrain.cpp
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp: In member function 'void Terrain::initTerrain()':
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp:65:62: error: 'random_shuffle' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp: In member function 'void Terrain::move(float)':
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp:158:6: error: 'm_tPosition' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp: In member function 'void Terrain::initBlock(Block*)':
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp:270:72: error: 'random_shuffle' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp:289:74: error: 'random_shuffle' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/Terrain.cpp:304:78: error: 'random_shuffle' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/game_shared/__/__/Classes/Terrain.o] Error 1
```

The project was done in Xcode, but I'm compiling for android

Comment: Not an Xcode guy, but did you include "Terrain.h" in your Terrain.cpp file?

Comment: if included "Terrain.h"...

Comment: The same problem? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616915/c11-stdasync-in-android-ndk-does-not-work

Comment: Already tried that solution and it did not work...

Comment: Include the header file in which Terrain class is defined. The variable random_shuffle seems to be defined in it. If not so, then include the header in which random_shuffle is defined.